# Setting nodesep in RPN differs from nodesep set with \pscalculate

Tags: pstricks, pst-eucl

Why does `nodesep={!50 194 sqrt div}` differ from `nodesep=\pscalculate{50/sqrt(194)}`?

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=10mm,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\psset{unit=5mm}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](10,13)
    \pstTriangle(0,0){B}(10,0){D}(5,13){E}
    \pstGeonode([nodesep=\pscalculate{50/sqrt(194)}]{D}E){P}
    \pstGeonode([nodesep={!50 194 sqrt div}]{D}E){Q}
    \pscircle(E){!50 194 sqrt div}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with `\pstGeonode([nodesep=5]{D}E){Q}` or with `\pstGeonode([nodesep=!5]{D}E){Q}`  and I suppose you'll know what happens??

Comment: No, the correct Syntax is `\pstTriangle(0,0){B'}(10,0){D'}(6,13){E'}` or `\pstTriangle(0,0){B}(10,0){D}(6,13){E}`

Comment: And yes, `nodesep=Value with/without unit` No ! operator possible

Comment: Out of topic: How to disable white opaque rectangle bounding the label of `\pstLabelAB` of `pst-eucl`?

Comment: http://archiv.dante.de/~herbert/pst-eucl.tex  knows `\pstLabelAB*` and also `\pstLabelAB` without the star.  The first uses `\cput*` (old behaviour) and the second `\cput`

Comment: Thank you very much!